# Deny authenticated users from a folder using FormsAuthentication

Tags: asp.net, formsauthentication

I am using FormsAuthentication to prevent anonymous users from accessing any content on my site, other than the pages within /pages/security - this folder contains the login page, forgotten password, etc.

```
<authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
</system.web>
<location path="pages/security">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users ="?" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

This works fine, but I also want to deny access for AUTHENTICATED to the /pages/security pages, so that an authenticated user can't access the login page or other related pages.

The above doesn't work, so once logged-in I can still access the login page - what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this approach.

When a user is authenticated and you want to stop him from accessing login page etc. Then you can use these pages `Page_Load` event to check user's authenticity if they are authentic redirect them to other page.
For example

```
if(IsUserAuthentic())
{
     Response.Redirect("Home.aspx"); 
}
```

`IsUserAuthentic()` is your custom method which will check user's authenticity.

Comment: Yeah, I figured this would be the way to go, but I was hoping there was a more elegant solution.  It's strange that there isn't some way of controlling it via web.config